# AttributeError: type object 'tqdm_asyncio' has no attribute 'auto'

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

I am trying to use tqdm in order to show a progress bar. My code looks like this:

```
> def create_data_lists(fnames):

>     for file in tqdm.auto(fnames, desc="Html files loop"):
>         doSomething()
> 
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     folder_list = ['folder1', 'folder2']
>     filenames = ['file1', 'file2']
> 
>     for folder in folder_list:
>         create_data_lists(filenames)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: type object 'tqdm_asyncio' has no attribute 'auto'

On the other hand, if I run `for folder in tqdm.auto(folder_list):` instead (and remove tqdm from the inner loop), it runs perfectly.

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Thank you in advance